# Cassandra 2 Hector: range slice query on composite row key return empty rows

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

We are using ByteOrderedPartitioner to store time series for a new project, cql3 was okey for us just for a moment then we choose Hector to move on but now our range query doesn't work.

C* version: 2.0.7

Hector version: 1.0-5

**Schema:**

```
        ColumnFamilyDefinition cfd = HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition(
                keyspaceName, columnFamilyName,
                ComparatorType.UTF8TYPE);
        cfd.setComparatorTypeAlias("(IntegerType,IntegerType,IntegerType)");
        cfd.setKeyValidationClass("CompositeType(IntegerType,IntegerType,IntegerType)");
        cfd.setDefaultValidationClass(ComparatorType.UTF8TYPE.getClassName());
```

RowKey: 100:20:11

=> (name=column1, value=AAL, timestamp=1401745673543000)

=> (name=column2, value=NYC, timestamp=1401745673543002)

RowKey: 100:20:12

=> (name=column1, value=AAL, timestamp=1401745673543000)

=> (name=column2, value=TXA, timestamp=1401745673543002)

And so on..

**Query to iterate over all rows of cassandra Column Family**

```
    Composite startComposite = new Composite();
    startComposite.addComponent(0,100,EQUAL);
    startComposite.addComponent(1,20,EQUAL);
    startComposite.addComponent(2,11,EQUAL);

    Composite endComposite = new Composite();
    endComposite.addComponent(0,100,EQUAL);
    endComposite.addComponent(1,20, EQUAL);
    endComposite.addComponent(2,18,GREATER_THAN_EQUAL);

    int rowCount = 100;
    RangeSlicesQuery<Composite, String, String> rangeSlicesQuery = HFactory
            .createRangeSlicesQuery(ksp, CompositeSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get())
            .setColumnFamily(columnFamilyName)
            .setRange("", "", false, rowCount);

    rangeSlicesQuery.setKeys(startComposite, endComposite);
    QueryResult<OrderedRows<Composite, String, String>> result = rangeSlicesQuery.execute();

    System.out.println(result.get());
```

**Get empty rows:**

Rows({})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Cassandra anti-pattern.  There are very few good reasons to use ByteOrderedPartitioner, and this pattern is not one of them.  You'll end up with all writes and queries essentially hitting one node (or a small number of nodes, depending on your cluster size).

There are many good examples of time-series data models in Cassandra.  [Here is one from Datastax](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-time-series-with-cassandra).

Comment: You are right i have been analysing for a new schema that can run with Murmur3Partitioner and i get new stuff we change it because our CQL3 queries are using token function to go over all row keys requested:

token(year_month, day) >= token(201404,20) AND
token(year_month, day) <= token(201404,22)

If i change to Murmur3Partitioner i get:
InvalidRequestException(why:start key's token sorts after end key's token.  this is not allowed; you probably should not specify end key at all except with an ordered partitioner)

But about the hector rangeslicequery: Do you know why isn't working?

Comment: [Check out this article](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html) on how to page through all rows.  You cannot page through a range using a random partitioner, because the keys are not ordered.  If you want to do this, you need to write a query that includes all known keys in the range using `SELECT * FROM ks.table WHERE mykey IN (v1, v2, v3)`.  Since your keys are month/day/year, this should be straightforward to compute.